# How to remove group of record from list which satisfy some condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table record list which I got through a stored procedure

### Table

[image]

here I got 8 sensor record for each minute and their tempStatus, humStatus .

condition I want is 
1. if all status for particular timespan gets Pass then I have to remove all record of that dataDateTime span.
2. if any out of 8 sensor's temp or sensor fails for time span then i have to pick all record of that time span.

Means i want this
[image]

Here is stored procedure from which I get this records

```
SELECT [MachineID]
,sum([TempatureSetValue]) AS [TempatureSetValue]
,sum([HumiditySetValue]) AS [HumiditySetValue]
,sum([TempaturePresentValue]) AS [TempaturePresentValue]
,sum([HumidityPresentValue]) AS [HumidityPresentValue]
,[DataDateTime]
,[RealSensorID] as SensorId
,(CASE WHEN ( SUM([TempaturePresentValue]) > @maxTAlarm OR SUM([TempaturePresentValue]) < @minTAlarm ) THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END) AS TempStatus
,(CASE WHEN (sum([HumidityPresentValue]) > @maxHAlarm OR sum([HumidityPresentValue]) < @minHAlarm) THEN 'FAIL'ELSE 'PASS' END) AS HumStatus
FROM tblData
WHERE DataDateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND MachineID =@machineId
 GROUP BY [RealSensorID]
,[DataDateTime]
,[MachineID]
 ORDER BY [DataDateTime]
,[RealSensorID]
```

as a database is too large it takes time also,
I need a solution to get this result either by stored procedure or using LINQ in C# code.

Comment: In c# use a SQLDataAtpter to put results into a DataTable.  If you are using Entity the results are already in a DataTable.  Then in c# use dt.AsEnumerable().

Comment: issue is not where to get data, i already got that data in generic list. what i want is to remove all records for perticular timestamp if all status get PASS and and if any of sensor fails for perticular time stamp than keep all sensor for that time stamp